# How to decrypt sha1 encrypted string C#

Tags: c#

I've encrypted a string(hello) using SHA1 using below code. Please guide me to decrypt this string.

```
SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
foreach( byte b in hash)
{
    sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

While searching in internet, I didn't find decryption using SHA1, even in MSDN. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Consider doing a little research on what SHA1 and in general what hash functions **are** and waht they are used for.

Answer (score 8):

SHA is a hashing method.  It is not an encryption.  Therefore, it can not be reversed.

[Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)

Answer (score 5):

SHA-1 is an digest algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. You can not reverse a digest algorithm like SHA-1.

The only way would be to brute force all potential inputs and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

SHA-1 is a hashing algorithm, not an encryption one. It's impossible to 'decrypt'. Read about SHA-1 on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and keep in mind it is not safe security wise.